# Pycharm - no log file is generated when running from Run/Debug config

Tags: pycharm

I have Pycharm Community Edition 2017.2 for Windows. I've set up a simple logger like this.

```
def configure_logging():
    logger = logging.getLogger("debuglogger")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # create a file handler
    filepath = join(getcwd(), 'debug.log')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filepath, mode='w', encoding='UTF-8')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # create a logging format
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '[%(levelname).3s][%(module)20.20s:%(funcName)-20.20s]-> %(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    # add the handler to the logger
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger
```

main.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # configure the logger
    logger = configure_logging()
    logger.info("logging configured\n")
```

If I run main.py from PyCharm's **Run/Debug** option then the log file is not created. But, if I run the script from a **terminal** window in PyCharm then the log file is generated. What do I need to do to make loggging work with the Run/Debug window? As you can see I have give the full path to the log file but it still doesn't work.

Comment: in the "run/debug configuration" menu, do you specify a working directory?  if not, your log might be in the PyCharm working directory

Comment: Thanks. It works after I set a working directory. Is it possible to set a working directory at the Project level so that all my logs are in one place (say in a folder named "logs") for all modules in the project?

Comment: yes, i replied in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "running directory" per run or per project.
Per run:   run -> edit configurations -> add run/debug configuration for your script

You can also set a default option under "defaults"

Per project: file -> settings -> build, execution, deployment -> console -> python console